# How to assign register value to a global 'C' variable in .s file

Tags: arm

From the below assembler snippet code, I am trying to accesses the CPU id from the register r0, to a global variable and pass the CPU id as a parameter to a function. But I am unable to do it. Can any body please help me.

```
Processor: ARM7A based LS1021A
_SecureException_handler_init:
  mrc     p15,0,r0,c0,c0,5          /* Read Multiprocessor Affinity Register (MPIDR) */
  and     r0,r0,#0x3                /* Mask off CPU ID */
  cmp     r0,#0x0                   /* Determine if Core 0 */
  cpy r12,r13
  push {r11-r12,r14,pc}
  sub  r11,r12,#0x04
  ldr sp,=_cpu_id    /* get address of _cpu_id */
  ldr r0,[sp] 
except_setup_vector_funcs(_cpu_id )
```

Comment: is except_setup_vector_funcs a c function, is that what you're trying to pass the cpuid to?

Comment: The register ro contains the value 0 or 1. I am planing to read the value from ro register to global variable cpu_id and pass the cpu_id as parameter to the function except_setup_vector_funcs(_cpu_id )

Comment: If the value is in r0 already, then you should be able to just `bl except_setup_vector_funcs` ?